# Remove Reply-To email address

Tags: apex, email, workflow, apex-email-service, email-alert

I am working with the approval process. When the workflow send the email alert to the user. The mail contains the reply-to email adrress which is wrong.
I want to remove that option OR set it to the correct address.

I dont know from where it is coming. Please help !!!!!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we send email from Workflow we have an option to send from email address. You can change it from there.

[image]

You will find this option in email alert.

Comment: Hi  Sharma, Thank you. Actually this from email address and Reply-to email address are different. You can set this Reply-to option in the email template like:<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!relatedTo.Deal_Copy_Deal_Name__c}, {!relatedTo.Deal_Copy_Deal_Id__c} sent to you by {!relatedTo.Deal_Copy_Submitter__r.Name} for approval. ref:{!relatedTo.Sfdc_Record_ID__c} " recipientType="User" relatedToType="Approver_History__c" replyTo="{!$Label.DealApprovalReplyTo}"> in the meta data file.

Comment: Here I have given the wrong address in replyTo field

Comment: @Jury yes we can set it from there as well. If we don't set it there then it pick address from here.